# UITableView And UICollectionView inside scrollView not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a tableView and a collectionView inside scrollView. Both of them have constraints for left, right, top and bottom. But both views are now visible when inside scrollView

Why may it be ?

Answer (score 0):

I think scrollViews Need to know width and height for its subViews

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Disable scroll for table view and collection view.
2. Resize the height of table view and collection view as per its content (If Dynamic height)

Comment: check height of tablview and collectionview when you resizing the frame of both. else post code here.